# getExtras method retrieves a null object when I passed it correctly

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I'm passing some data between two activities but I'm getting a NullPointerException where I shouldn't...

I start the activity like this

```
Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
     NewActivity.class);

i.putExtra(SERVICE_ID, serviceId);
i(serviceActivityIntent);
```

And I try to get the serviceId on the other side in this fashion

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/* I also tried this just for in case my object was in the savedInstanceState */    
//      mServiceId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null
//        : (GroupServiceId) savedInstanceState
//          .getSerializable(ServicesActivity.SERVICE_ID);

      if (mServiceId == null) {
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       mServiceId = extras != null ? (GroupServiceId) extras
         .getSerializable(ServicesActivity.SERVICE_ID) : null;    // <-- this is line 86
      }
```

I think I've done everything okay and I'm running out of clues here...
Here's the exception I get:

```
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.pfc/org.pfc.NewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at org.smepp.datatypes.smm.GroupServiceId.readObject(GroupServiceId.java:105)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1537)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1460)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2139)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:1945)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1822)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1189)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at org.pfc.NewActivity.onCreate(NewActivity.java:86)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
01-14 13:11:57.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1019):     ... 11 more
```

Obviously, the object "extras" from the intent is null when the second activity starts, but I keep wondering why...

By the way, GroupServiceId implements Serializable so that's not the problem, or I think so...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extras bundle isn't `null`, it's `GroupServiceId.readObject()` that's crashing. Your serialization is screwed. Suggest you post code for `GroupServiceId`.

Comment: Exactly, something was going on with serialization... That class is perfectly serializable in Java SE but not in Android for some reason. I serialized the class field by field and worked. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to add your object using the extras.putSerializable() method and then you can cast it when you get it back. Here's a link to a previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548489/android-problem-with-serializable-object-put-into-intent)