# Storing complex object to a file in android application

Tags: java, android, file, store

```
FileOutputStream fout = context.getApplicationContext()
                    .openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
out.writeObject(complexObject);
```

Will this code work for a complexObject which is an instance of a complex class. By complex I mean that it might contain several arraylists of instances of other classes, many instance variables?

Comment: You tried it and...? It's much more interesting/beneficial to answer *actual problems* than *easily-testable hypothetical problems* :) It also provides a start for searches as for causes and solutions. (The documentation is also a good place to start.)

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but I'm interested whether it would be working on all android devices.

Comment: "Yes, it should." This is handled through the standard Serialization specification. [An old intro is here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). However, [there may be bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548489/android-problem-with-serializable-object-put-into-intent) in some cases (this one will not affect the case described, however).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) can serialize a complex tree of objects as long as all objects in this tree implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). It also serializes all java primitive types.