# Intent putextra serializable object array

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent

my problem is putextra method with serializable object array. I mean if i try bottom code it throws `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:`

Here 's the code :

```
 class Example implements Serializable
    {
      private int ID; // It has getters and setters and also other variables.
    }

Intent inte=new Intent(this,OTHERCLASS.class);
Example[] examples=new Example[]; // It's just an example.
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putSerializable("Details", examples);
inte.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(inte);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why Serializable and why not Parcelable?

Comment: @PankajKumar passing *Seriazable* extra is far more easy and short way than *Parceable*, he is asking for solution not a suggestion

Comment: Actually i don't know how to use parcelable can you give me an example ?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar actually yes ;)

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Did you asked the question? I think no :). so Why are you putting your leg here. He has the sense where what should he do or don't. And first read about Serializable and Parcelable and then mention me in commnet. hope you will find.

Comment: guys can you please focus my question ?

Comment: @PankajKumar hold on its not regarding you and me, *SO* is a platform for common users so think before you answer or comment, try to give solution rather than suggestions

Comment: @SercanOzdemir please post the complete *logcat*!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Can you point me where SO says that I can't give suggestions? Don't be too smart... Choice is mine.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.CTS.example.example$MyClass)

Comment: Try to put size of array. like `new Example[1];`

Comment: And You and for the very smart Guy : Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548489/android-problem-with-serializable-object-put-into-intent

Comment: this object array already filled before these codes. It's just an example to show you how.

Comment: and it's jus implementing Serializable !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because you can't serialize a inner class without making its parent class serializable. Which in your case is your Activity. So simply create a new java file for your Example class

Comment: This actually helped me a lot!!! I was passing an object of type ClassA that was serializable but I had another object inside that ClassA object whose class was not serialized. Making all classes that are passed serializable fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Although your class is serializable, an Array of items with your class (`Example[]`) is not serializable.</strike> Edit: *Thanks @gomino for pointing out that this was wrong. I just assumed this was the reason for the problem without actually thinking about it.*

Also, it would be more efficient to use a Parcelable instead. [You can find a tutorial here](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html).

Comment: could you give me an parcelable example ?

Comment: first hit on google: http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html

Comment: my object class has lots of object so it's kinda impossible to change it to parcelable.For example My object class has ArrayList<String>,lots of string and int variables... So Isn't there a chance to do it with serializable way ?

Comment: Or i will change my variable static which i don't want.

Comment: OK, i changed my variable to static. But as i read parcelable works on it. SO i'll accept this answer.

Comment: And take +1 from my side. Although some one was crushed my mind :D

Comment: Just to make it clear: you could use a Serializable, but it wouldn't be as efficient (quick to run). Java would do a similar job to what you needed to do to implement Parcelable.

Comment: Yes we can use, but in Android there is drawback of Serializable. Thats the reason Android says to use Parcelable

Comment: Why do you say "an Array of items with your class (Example[]) is not serializable", array are always serializable in java